# Where to find the onPremissesImmutableId?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I´m writing an little application to create new user on an Azure AD.
Even following all the instructions in [Create User Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java) I allways get an Http Error 400 (Bad Request).

The only thing I´m not providing is an attribute named *onPremissesImmutableId*. Assuming I must provide it, problem is I don't know where to find such a value.

This is the Json I'm posting:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Name Surname",
  "mailNickname": "Surname",
  "userPrincipalName": "name.surname@XXXX.onmicrosoft.com", 
  "passwordProfile" : {
     "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
     "password": "p@ssw0#D"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Just after I posted the question I had the idea to review the password policy active on my AD tenant and I found out that it was the problem. So I just had to set a new password to match the policy and everything worked just fine.